# VSCode debugger sudden ECONNREFUSED error, cannot connect debugger to Firefox

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, firefox, vscode-debugger

Debugging with Firefox in VS Code suddenly stopped working on Windows, launching or attaching the debugger always results in error message `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:6000`.

Tried deleting all VSCode related configuration and cache files and re-install latest VSCode in user mode, installed latest Firefox Developer Edition and tried debugging with `default` profile and non-persistent profile to see if the problem lies elsewhere.

Tried different debugger launch configurations.

None of this had any effect and problem still persists.

Comment: This seems related to the recent update 1.82.1 as I'm seeing it too.

Comment: I attempted to use Chrome debugger (via Javascript Debugger extension) and it worked fine with my default setup for Firefox (sans the `reAttach` property). This is the workaround I will use for now.

Comment: https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug/issues/341

Comment: I too am seeing this in v1.82.2. Thanks for the report @BuZZ-dEE

Comment: Breakpoint failures with Chrome around the same time. Installed an earlier version of the JavaScript Debugger (v2023.9.1317) and the breakpoints began to work again. The _package.json_ dependencies are up to date, and using node v20.6.1

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

---

You might not need to setup port proxy with the command from original solution if you use this setting in your attach configuration as mentioned by some people:

```
"host": "127.0.0.1"
```

Also breakpoints don't work for some reason.

Issue seems related to VSCode update **1.82**.

### **Original solution**

---

Resolved on my own by redirecting port `6000` from IPv6 loopback to IPv4 loopback.

For **microsoft windows**:

Open windows terminal or command line as administrator and type command

```
netsh interface portproxy add v6tov4 listenaddress=::1 listenport=6000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=6000
```

If you use different port for debugging don't forget to substitute it in the command.

I found out you have to start Firefox with argument `-start-debugger-server 6000` and use `attach` launch configuration like below in VS Code in order for it to work correctly if debugger stops launching after setting up proxy...

```
{
    "name": "Attach Firefox",
    "type": "firefox",
    "request": "attach",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
}
```

Comment: Property `host` is not allowed, if you use `"request": "launch"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and it is [fixed in version 2.9.10](https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug/issues/341#issuecomment-1736923971).

Commit: https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug/commit/c0a391de7b1a4b2468ada28e67fb4ad54d0dc671

Pull-Request: https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug/pull/342/files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after updating to 1.82.2. I eventually discovered I was using the "Debugger for Firefox" extension, which I had forgotten about.

When I checked the settings for the extension, they were all blank.

I added a value in **Firefox:Executable** & **Firefox:Port** (Note: this was 6000, not 4200)

This fixed it for me, but I do not know if this was just my settings disappearing, or if the update changed the way the blank settings were handled.